# Check if Localizable.strings file is valid

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, localization

I am creating `Localizable.strings` file programatically. I am downloading the file from server and showing the localization from that file.

But if there is some error in file then my localization don't work. It shows me the keys. If on server I edit the localization file and I added string as

```
"HELLO_WORLD" = Hello
```

Here, the key is correct but value is not in correct format. The format should be as

```
"HELLO_WORLD" = "Hello";
```

How can I programatically check at runtime if my `Localizable.strings` file does not contain any error and is valid?

Comment: According to wikipedia, xx.strings file is kind of reduced old-style ASCII property list; it's a dictionary without parenthesis. So, `plutil` works fine to verify its format.

Answer (score 107):

Use `plutil` from the Terminal:

```
plutil -lint Localizable.strings
```

Comment: great thanks. Xcode 9 and terminal  are used and still working to help be debug

Answer (score 38):

In addition to @Aderstedt's answer:

`plutil -lint Localizable.strings` does work, but you have to run it for each version of the file. E.g

1. `cd` into your project root
2. `cd en.lproj` - you can replace this with any localisation you are working with.
3. `plutil -lint Localizable.strings`

When you run step 3, you will either be shown an error, telling you what is wrong with your file. Or you will be told the file is OK

Comment: You can simply run `plutil -lint **/*.string`.

Comment: `find . -name \*.strings -exec plutil -lint {} +` works OK, too.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned above `plutil` (property list utility) is a great tool to validate your `.plist` and `.strings` files if you edit them manually. You can apply it to all your `.strings` file by combining it with `find`. In your project directory run

```
find . -name *.strings -exec plutil -lint {} \;
```

or use

```
find . -path ./DerivedData -prune -o -name *.strings -exec plutil -lint {} \;
```

if you like to exclude your `DerivedData` directory (as I usually do).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found `plutil` isn't 'detailed' enough. The folks editing the files wanted something that would tell them more exactly what is wrong

**plutil is just too broad.**

so I wrote a quick&dirty java tool to test a strings file:

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/parseAndValidateAppleStringsFile

disclaimer: my code

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers but they wasn't focus on the main points is "**programmatically** check **at runtime**".
My suggestion is:

1. Programmatically find the path of your downloaded file program (Like .../Documents/YourApp.bundle/fr-FR.lproj/Localizable.strings)

   ```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:@"ja"];
   ```
2. Convert it to array of strings

   ```
   NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:localizablePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
   NSArray *allLinedStrings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
   ```
3. Check all line from allLinedStrings manually or with Regular Expression. Following code is an example of manually check with some simple rules:

   ```
   for (NSString *line in allLinedStrings) {
       if (line.length >= 2) {
           NSString *firstTwoCharacters = [line substringToIndex:2];

           if (![firstTwoCharacters isEqualToString:@"//"]){
               if (![line containsString:@"\";"]) {
                   NSLog(@"Invalid line");
               }

               NSUInteger numberOfOccurrences = [[line componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] count];
               if (numberOfOccurrences < 4) {
                   NSLog(@"Invalid line");
               }
           }
       }
       else if (line.length > 0) {
           NSLog(@"Invalid line");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Maybe it's better to invoke `plutil` to check string files, instead of write your own method.

Answer (score -1):

Use the tool below, which is better than plutil. It has other features to detect missing localized string.

https://github.com/Rocker007/XCLocale

and use below option to validate your localized string file

```
./XCLocale.py -cf <iOS project path>
```

This tool will tell you exact line no for syntax error and also detect some of syntax error which is not detected by your latest Xcode version

For example:

```
#"screen.title"  =  " screen 1";
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21994681)

Comment: @juzraai, Sure will add more info this post.